# im-config ubuntu. pls explain what all that means?

Tags: input-method

i can't find any talk on im-config all over youtube or internet. 
apparently it is a field that is very left unattended.

the words in it are so confusing to meaningless to me.  i have

i have these input method system onboard:
fcitx
IBUS
XIM

i need to type english, chinese (google pinyin instead of sogou from china) and germany.

i set up my windows os in the same method.  i used  Ctrl+1 for english, ctrl+2 for chinese, ctrl+3 for german language.

anybody can show me how to achieve this ? it is all now a mess.. because all the features and function of input method in "languages" is totally meaningless to me.

andrew

im-config:

---

Current configuration for the input method:
 * Active configuration: fcitx (normally missing)
 * Normal automatic choice: ibus (normally ibus or fcitx or uim)
 * Override rule: zh_CN,fcitx:zh_TW,fcitx:zh_HK,fcitx:zh_SG,fcitx:ja_JP,fcitx:ko_KR,fcitx:vi_VN,fcitx
 * Current override choice:  (en_US)
 * Current automatic choice: ibus
 * Number of valid choices: 3 (normally 1)
The override rule is defined in /etc/default/im-config.
The configuration set by im-config is activated by re-starting X.
Explicit selection is not required to enable the automatic configuration if the active one is default/auto/cjkv/missing.
  Available input methods: ibus fcitx xim
Unless you really need them all, please make sure to install only one input method tool.

---

input method options
[image: input method options]

his is the virtual keyboard of chinese input method ZH
[image: this is the virtual keyboard of chinese input method ZH]

ibus-setup screen shots

[image]

chinese configuration

[image]

this is my im-config , although i have not a slightest idea what it says:

[[image: im-config[1]]

i hav google pinyin and fcitx installed. 
i also have ibus and ibus-libpinyin installed

the problem is, the input method setup is so difficult for me to understand that i am just twitching here and there without solid knowledge what does it do..  hence sometime it works, and sometime it does not work. google pinyin works for a few while, but it is not like what i like it to work as what i have used in windows google pinyin.. i tried to make it better, and as i said, i just twitching it here and there and at the end it is gone. 
hence i saw other person using ibus to do chinese input.. i also tried, but it does not work.. i have chinese input installed, but the output is just english character, same as english input..

Comment: Which desktop environment are you on?

Comment: i am using gnome classic. why  ? is there anything to do with desktop environment ?

Comment: Have you tried this guide: http://blog.zedyeung.com/2018/08/05/Ubuntu-18-04-fcitx-chinese-input-setup-google-and-sogou/? And about the keyboard shortcut, you can find it it the System Setting of Ubuntu.

Comment: The "Chinese" input source is just an alias to "English (US)", and thus redundant since the list of input sources already includes "English (US)". To be able to use Intelligent Pinyin you should add "Chinese (Intelligent Pinyin)" to the list of input sources. And you should do that in Settings -> Region & Language, not in "IBus Preferences".

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons why I asked about the desktop environment:

1. To determine if the *Language Support* tool is present, which I then think it is. *Language Support* has a simplified GUI to `im-config`.
2. You mentioned that you want to use Google Pinyin, which would require the Fcitx IM framework. The problem with that is that Fcitx does not work well with GNOME, which is designed to be used with IBus.

As regards the `im-config` UI, it's far too verbose IMNSHO. So I recommend that you simply use *Language Support* to set the IM framework of your choice.

But since you are on GNOME, I would recommend that you choose IBus, and install `ibus-libpinyin` instead of struggling with some Fcitx IM.